# Prevent globbing after variable substitution

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, glob

What is the most elegant way to use shell variable (BASH) that contain characters reserved for globbing (filename completion) that trigger some unwanted substitutions? Here is the example:

```
for file in $(cat files); do
   command1 < "$file"
   echo "$file"
done
```

The file names contain characters like '[' or ']'. I have basically two ideas:

1) Turn off globbing via set -f: I need it somewhere else

2) Escape the file names in files: BASH complains about "file not found" when piping into stdin

Thx for any suggestion

*Edit: The only answer missing is how to read from a file with name containing special characters used for globbing when the filename is in a shell variable "$file", e. g. command1 < "$file".*

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to switching between `set -f` and `set +f` you could perhaps just apply a single `set -f` to a subshell since the environment of the parent shell would not by affected by this at all:

```
(
set -f
for file in $(cat files); do
   command1 < "$file"
   echo "$file"
done
)


# or even

sh -f -c '
   for file in $(cat files); do
      command1 < "$file"
      echo "$file"
   done
'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can turn off globbing with `set -f`, then turn it back on later in the script with `set +f`.

Comment: This probably works but if you have to disable and enable the globbing feature in each cycle of a loop it is IMO not elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Use `while read` instead.

```
cat files | while read file; do
    command1 < "$file"
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: This is a good hint, thanks. It will prevent globbing in the list construction of the for loop. But the two execution lines will still trigger globbing after variable substitution.