# Python: Handle globbing within a script

Tags: python, shell, glob

```
$ script.py *.txt
```

I want to run script.py on all .txt files in this directory, which include 1.txt, 2.txt, and 3.txt. There's two approaches I can think of to this: having the python script handle globbing, or having the shell spawn multiple processes.

Having the script handle globbing is the approach I prefer.

According to [Prevent globbing after variable substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452107/prevent-globbing-after-variable-substitution) I can use `set -f` to turn it off. How would I be able to specify this option exclusively for Python scripts?

Comment: What about the third approach: let the shell spawn one process with multiple arguments. That's the normal, default way that things work, and very easy to deal with in your Python script (either by looping over `sys.argv[1:]`, or by using `fileinput`).

Comment: It's a good idea, but I'd like it to work for different scripts that take in a variable number of parameters, including when I'm utilizing `optparse` or `argparse`.

Comment: I don't see how that's a problem at all. Just about every tool that comes with any Unix system, and 90% of the third-party programs and scripts you'll find out there, use `optparse` or `argparse` or other libraries, and take a variable number of parameters, and work just fine with shell globbing. If yours doesn't, you've probably designed the interface wrong, and that's what you need to fix.

Comment: hmm, I think you're right. I'm guessing you mean, wrap it in a shell script that will expand the parameters with `$@`? If you write it out in an answer I will accept it

Comment: I thought about suggesting that, but really, you don't even need that. If your `script.py` can work with multiple input files (i.e., multiple arguments left over after parsing out the options), in the same way that, e.g., `ls` does, then shell globbing would present no problems to work around in the first place. There are some tools where such an interface wouldn't be reasonable (e.g., ImageMagick's `convert` has options interspersed between the arguments; `find` obviously needs to do its own blobbing…), but they're a rare exception, not the rule. Why do you think your script is an exception?

Comment: Okay, it seems like the shell just shoves all matching files, space delimited, into the space occupied by `*.txt`. I wasn't aware of this since the extra arguments went missing after going into a script that didn't explicitly handle them. Given that fact your original comment makes sense. Thanks for helping me pin down the issue.

My original question, although defunct, is still an interesting question that I'm curious to see how someone would tackle the issue as originally envisioned

Comment: Well, the shell deals in arguments, not a space-delimited string. (Otherwise, it wouldn't work with files with spaces in them, or if there were quotes anywhere, etc.) So it replaces the single argument `*.txt` with multiple arguments (similar to what Python `a[5:6] = glob(a[5])` would do), then passes the resulting argument list to your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you need the gobbling inside the script (counting the total number of files processed, for example), it's possible to use:

```
script.py '*.txt'
```

or

```
script.py "*.txt"
```

Comment: This works well. For commands run without quotes, is there any way to automatically patch on quotes around each argument?

Comment: @Brian  Not on a command-by-command basis, that I know of.  Either globally by `set -f`, or by quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this via Python globbing? A shell script would be perfect, IMHO, and you separate the core functionality of what your python script is supposed to do, vs. the menial task of running it for all the `*.txt` files in the directory.

Comment: As @mario pointed out, there are cases in which the script might need to deal with metadata from other files. Not opposed to it though. I'm not sure how to alias python into a shell script either.

Comment: Are you asking how to call a python script from a shell script? A line that says `python myScript.py` from the shell script would be just fine, assuming `python` is available in your `$PATH` somewhere already

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge number of files in the directory, [iglob()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) would be better.  You have to pass in the glob parameter as a string:

```
$ script.py "*.txt"
```